# Terraform - regular expression

Tags: regex, terraform

I have the following list

```
variable "global_aws" {
  default = [
    "10.20.16.0/20",
    "192.168.0.0/16"
  ]
}
```

I want to extract only the subnet prefix so I can get `10.20.16.0` and `192.168.0.0` respectively

I have this so far:

```
name = "${replace(element(var.global_aws, count.index), "//*/", "")}"
```

Currently, I get:

```
name:"10.20.16.0.020"
name:"192.168.0.016"
```

**Desired output**

```
name:"10.20.16.0.0"
name:"192.168.0.0"
```

Comment: Did you tried : `name = "${replace(element(var.global_aws, count.index), "/\/d*/", "")}"`

Comment: just did and got: illegal char escape

Comment: `name = "${replace(element(var.global_aws, count.index), '/\/d*/', '')}"`

Comment: thanks, but got same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to regex out the prefix you can use the [`cidrhost()` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#cidrhost-iprange-hostnum-) instead:

```
$ terraform console
> cidrhost("10.20.16.0/20", 0)
10.20.16.0
```